# unable to achieve the scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to take a Scroll View for this images. The layout should be able to scroll in vertical direction. I am taking Linear Layout inside Linear Layout but unable to achieve this. Can anyone please tell me how to tackle this problem.

Comment: <ScrollView ... <LinearLayout ... <Your Layouts for displaying images  (ScrollView can have only one child)

Comment: A `ScrollView` can only contain one child.

Comment: the images are static??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
   >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
         >
// Add Images here
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Instead use Relative Layout...

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView Like this :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!-- your code goes here -->
            </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
</TableLayout>
```